# Найти сумму чисел, которые находятся в определенном расположении в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы

Необходимо посчитать сумму чисел в массиве, расположенных по краям (из файла на вход поступает матрица). В результате надо вывести сумму этих чисел.

Пример входных данных:

[image]

Неудачная реализация в моем коде:

```
void zadanie(int &sum,int &real_rows,int &real_columns, float **arr)
{
    for (int j{}; j<real_columns; j++)
    {
        for (int i{}; i < real_columns; i++)
        {
            sum += *(*(arr+i)+j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто так хочу поделится кодом ниже:

```
float zadanie(float** matrix, int rows, int cols) {
float sum = 0;
//Условие если только одна строка
if (rows == 1) {
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
        sum += matrix[0][c];
}
//Условие если только один столбец
else if (cols == 1) {
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        sum += matrix[r][0];
}
else {
    //Складываем верхнюю строчку и нижнюю
    if(rows > 0)
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
            sum += matrix[0][c] + matrix[rows - 1][c];
    //Складываем числа по бокам
    if(cols > 0)
        for (int r = 1; r < rows - 1; ++r)
            sum += matrix[r][0] + matrix[r][cols - 1];
}
return sum;
}
```

Да достаточно большой для такой легкой задачи, но и у него есть преимущества. Он быстрее, чем проходить по всем элементам матрицы!))

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy функция возвращает 0 если `rows == 0` или `cols == 0` т.к если `rows == 0` и `cols == 0`, то попадает в else где не пройдет ни в один цикл.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вы правы. Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
double zadanie(double **arr, int rows,int columns) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
            if (r == 0 || r == rows-1 || с == 0 || с == columns-1)
                sum += arr[r][c];
    return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Интересно что можно в те же два цикла уложится и найти сумму намного быстрее.

Comment: Конечно, если идти по краям, или сразу прибавлять не c++, а на весь "просвет". Но потянет ли ТС?

Comment: Думаю, потянет.